# Why did Claire give John the earring?

Tags: analysis, breakfast-club

In the movie [*The Breakfast Club*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088847/), why did Molly Ringwald's character Claire give the big honking diamond earring to Judd Nelson's character John?

I realize there is a new friendship there, but was there deeper meaning which the movie makers wanted to convey?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He'd been mocking those earrings earlier; with this gesture she shows him she isn't as materialistic as he accused her of being. John said that "you got everything and I got shit"; by giving him her earring she negates that accusation.

[From the script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/breakfast_club.html):

> Bender: Don't you ever...ever! Compare
>   yourself to me! Okay? You got
>   everything, and I got shit! Fuckin'
>   Rapunzel, right? School would
>   probably fucking shut down if you
>   didn't show up! "Queenie isn't
>   here!" I like those earrings Claire.
>
> Claire: Shut up...
>
> Bender: Are those real diamonds, Claire?
>
> Claire: Shut up!
>
> Bender: I bet they are...did you work, for the money 
>   for those earrings?
>
> Claire: Shut... Your mouth!
>
> Bender: Or did your daddy buy those?
>
> Claire: Shut up!
>
> Bender: I bet he bought those for you! I bet those are a Christmas
>   gift! Right? You know what I got for Christmas this year? It was a
>   banner fuckin' year at the old Bender family! I got a carton of
>   cigarettes. The old man grabbed me and said "Hey! Smoke up Johnny!"
>   Okay, so go home'n cry to your daddy, don't cry here, okay?

There's [more discussion here](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=348170):

> > **Rubystreak:**
> >
> > Claire gives John her diamond earring. Is that meaningful?
>
> **Moe:**
>
> I think so. **It was symbolic of the breaking down of the artificial
>   wall of affluence she kept herself behind** to protect her (in a
>   psycho-social sense, as opposed to physical) from the have-nots. In
>   that moment **she realized that the connection she felt with John was
>   worth more than her material possessions**, especially since she didn't
>   even "work for the money to pay for" them.
>
> **The whole movie is about the breaking down of artificial walls between
>   high school cliques** - walls created by parents and the home
>   environment that they grew up in. They realize, if only for a day,
>   that underneath it all, they're really all the same and all deal with
>   the same issues.
>
> Will it last? I'd like to think that at some level they'll all take
>   the insights from that day with them. I think all teenagers (or at
>   least introspective ones) have to practice a sort of doublethink where
>   they fully embrace their clique identities while also at some level
>   realizing the silliness of it all. But no doubt, come Monday morning,
>   they're all right back in their respective cliques.

Comment: That last bit was exactly what I was wondering about ... awesome!

Comment: I've reluctantly downvoted. A webchat between two people on the internet (neither of whom had any connection to the film) isn't substantive.

Comment: Then by all means, @Richard, please post something more substantive.